# Does embedding in golang violate law of demeter?

Tags: oop, go, struct, embedding, law-of-demeter

This is what the **Effective GO** had to say about *Embedding* in golang

> When we embed a type, the methods of that type become methods of the outer type, but when they are invoked the receiver of the method is the inner type, not the outer one

I had a code snippet where I had `Struct User` defined as follows

```
type User struct {
    Name     string
    Password string
    *sql.Tx
}
```

And then I call `u.Query("some query here")` etc. I had done this specifically so that I could avoid calls like `u.Transaction.Query("query")`, which clearly violates *Law of Demeter*. Now after reading the docs and effective go, I am doubtful about merits of the first approach as well.
Am I violating *Law of Demeter*? If yes the how can I avoid it ?

Comment: In that code, I'd be more worried about [SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Does an SQL transaction have anything to do with a user?

Comment: @Ainar-G User wants to query the database. Then would it be violation of SoC ?

Comment: Moreover, even if I pull out the transaction and replace it with another object(say Superpower), I still believe it violates Law of Demeter

Comment: Can any of downvoters explain what the issue with the question is ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The embedding concept somewhat violates [*Law of Demeter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) as it *doesn't hide* the fact that a type was embedded *if* the type itself is *exported*. Note that embedding an unexported type **does not** violate LoD (you can't refer to unexported fields and methods).

But this *doesn't force* you to refer to promoted fields or methods in a way that also violates LoD. Embedding itself is just a technique so that you can "outsource" common, shared code to other types; or from another point of view to make use of other types when creating new ones. The way you refer to the promoted fields or methods of the embedded types is what may violate the law.

As you said, if you call it as `u.Tx.Query()`, that is a clear violation of *Law of Demeter*: you are using the implementation detail that `User` embeds `*sql.Tx`.

But if you call it like this: `u.Query()` that is ok. This form does not expose or take advantage of the fact that `*sql.Tx` is embedded. This form will continue to work if implementation changes and `*sql.Tx` will not be embedded anymore (e.g. it is changed to be a "regular" field or removed completely, and a `User.Query()` method is added).

If you don't want to allow access to the field value of the exported embedded type, make it an unexported regular field and add an "explicit" `User.Query()` method which may delegate to the field, e.g.:

```
type User struct {
    Name     string
    Password string
    tx       *sql.Tx // regular field, not embedded; and not exported
}

func (u *User) Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (*sql.Rows, error) {
    return u.tx.Query(query, args...)
}
```

**Further notes:**

In the example, if `u.Query()` is used, the clients using this are not affected if internals of `User` are changed (it doesn't matter if `u.Query()` denotes a promoted method or it denotes a method of `User`, that is: `User.Query()`).

If `sql.Tx` changes, yes, `u.Query()` might not be valid anymore. But an incompatible `sql.Tx` is unlikely to happen. And if you're the developer of the changed package, and making incompatible changes, it is your responsibility to change other code that depends on your incompatible change. Doing so (properly updating `u.Query()`) the client who calls `u.Query()` will not be affected, the client still doesn't need to know something changed under the hood.

This is exactly what LoD guarantees: if you use `u.Query()` instead of `u.Tx.Query()`, if the `User` changes internally, the client calling `u.Query()` does not need to know or worry about that. LoD is not a bad thing. You should not drop it. You may choose what principles you follow, but you should also think and not follow everything a chosen principle dictates all the time at any costs.

One more thing to clear: LoD does not involve API incompatible changes. What it offers is if followed, internal changes of an entity will not have effect on other entities using the "public" face of the entity. If `sql.Tx` is changed in a drastic way that `Tx.Query()` will not be available anymore, that is not "covered" by LoD.

Comment: I believe LOD was in existence to make sure that the changes in one class are propagated to other in a very limited way. Both the approaches you mention, do not seem to solve the problem.(I might be totally wrong but that's how I feel, as delegation to a new method still remains a code smell)

Comment: @Anony-mouse In the example, if `u.Query()` is used, the clients using this are not affected if internals of `User` are changed (it doesn't matter if `u.Query()` denotes a promoted method or it denotes a method of `User`, that is: `User.Query()`).

Comment: What about the case where `tx` itself changes? Now `u.Query()` might not be a valid operation at all. Since I have introduced this dependency,  any issue with `tx` will directly influence my `User` which should be avoided right? One more thing is LoD such a bad thing? Should I dump it altogether?

Comment: @Anony-mouse If `sql.Tx` changes, yes, `u.Query()` might not be valid anymore. But an incompatible `sql.Tx` is unlikely to happen. And if you're the developer of the changed package, and making incompatible changes, it is your responsibility to change other code that depends on your incompatible change. Doing so (properly updating `u.Query()`) the client who calls `u.Query()` will not be affected, the client still doesn't need to know something changed under the hood.

Comment: @Anony-mouse This is exactly what LoD guarantees: if you use `u.Query()` instead of `u.Tx.Query()`, if the `User` changes internally, the client calling `u.Query()` does not need to know or worry about that. LoD is not a bad thing. You should not drop it. You may choose what principles you follow, but you should also think and not follow everything a chosen principle dictates all the time at any costs.

Comment: @Anony-mouse One more thing to clear: LoD does not involve API incompatible changes. What it offers is if followed, internal changes of an entity will not have effect on other entities using the "public" face of the entity. If `sql.Tx` is changed in a drastic way that `Tx.Query()` will not be available anymore, that is not "covered" by LoD.

Comment: Soory I was busy, I think with this comment you have pretty much answered the question. I am closing it now.

Comment: can you  edit the answer above and add the details to it. It might be better for future references.

Comment: @Anony-mouse Done. Thanks for the suggestion.